# Wrap every array of a array group into divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I wrap all array values per row, not as summery of all? My code gives me all arrays in every row.

```js
var numbers = $("#table > .row > .numbers").text().split(','); // to get them as array

$.each(numbers, function(index, value) { // wrap every array number in a div
  $('#table > .row').append("<div>" + value + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="numbers">2,3,8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="numbers">6,7,2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is like this:

```
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="numbers">
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
       <div>8</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="numbers">
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
       <div>8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to wrap every array of a array group inside `.row`, not all together of the whole `#table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your logic is that you're selecting *all* `.numbers` elements and creating one array with every value. Then as you iterate through the array, you append all the values in each `.numbers` element, not just the ones relevant to that specific element.

To do what you require you can provide a function to jQuery's `html()` method which accepts the HTML *of the current element* as an argument.

You can then `split()` this in to an array of values and `map()` it to create an array containing HTML strings with the values wrapped in `div` elements. If you return this to `html()` it will then append that content within the current `.numbers` element as it iterates through them all:

```js
$('.numbers').html((i, html) => html.split(',').map(i => `<div>${i}</div>`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="numbers">2,3,8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="numbers">6,7,2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wau, that's a very interesting way! Big thx for your support and explanation.